# Very slow ExecuteNonQuery (Stored Procedure) vs fast execution using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Although there are many questions on this topic going around, none of the suggestions seem to work.
I've got a couple of stored procedures which should be run on a daily basis - some of these stored procedures are quite straight forward, others a bit more tricky. But even the simplest of procedures will run indefinitely when called from a C# program (console) using the SqlClient.
This client is running on the server and should be promoted to a windows service when it's actually functioning.

What I've tried so far.

1. Add ARITHABORT ON (or OFF) as first execute after connection initialization.
2. Add ARITHABORT ON (or OFF) as first command in the Stored Procedure
3. Using `WITH RECOMPILE`
4. Add ARITHABORT as a global configuration thing.

(`EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'64'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO`)

The stored procedures (all of them) have *no* input parameters and the simplest (the only one I currently use) is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_clean_messageLog]
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set arithabort on;

    DELETE FROM MessageLog WHERE Moment < GETDATE() - 60;

    DELETE FROM MessageLog WHERE Moment < GETDATE() - 30 AND [Status] = 200;
END
```

There are no messages to be actually deleted and in SSMS the stored procedures executes (as expected) within milliseconds.
From the C# Console Application however it takes forever (literally).

Main-method:

```
const int TIME_OUT = 900000; // 15 minutes
            timer.Stop();
            foreach (var command in commands.Where(command => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command)))
            {
                var start = DateTime.Now;
                WriteEvent(string.Format("Starting: {0}", command), EventLogEntryType.Information);
                using (var sql = new Lib.Data.SqlServerHelper(connectionString))
                {
                    sql.newCommand(command.Trim());
                    sql.execute(TIME_OUT); 
                }
                WriteEvent(string.Format("Done in {0} seconds", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds), EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
```

Does anyone have suggestions?

### EDIT

The sqlHelper is just a basic (very simple) wrapper. But even when I change the above code to this:

```
foreach (var command in commands.Where(command => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command)))
            {
                var start = DateTime.Now;
                WriteEvent(string.Format("Starting: {0}", command), EventLogEntryType.Information);
                using (var sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sql.Open();
                    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command.Trim(), sql) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                WriteEvent(string.Format("Done in {0} seconds", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds), EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
```

It's exactly the same.

### EDIT #2

Is there an option I can schedule these stored procedures to be run by SQL Server itself on an interval or specific time?

### SOLVED

Kinda, although I've never found an actual C# solution to my problem using the SQL Server Agent did the trick. The C# processes were locked due to deadlock issues - which sometimes also occur on the jobs (not as many as the console program), but we're working on that.

Comment: Run a profiler trace when you run the proc from the app, and see if the proc is really taking a long time, as opposed to the network or your app.

Comment: Are you sure that when you call from Application your query isn't blocked by another?

Comment: It's probably because of the overhead you have in SqlServerHelper, meaning that you have to open the db connection. Execute 2 queries, one after the other and measure the second one.

Comment: Remove "WITH RECOMPILE" and rebuild indexes.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx might help you here. - sounds like you are re-inventing the job scheduler to me.

Comment: +1 to checking if your app is being blocked by another query or open transaction (EXEC sp_who) and look for 1 in block for your app login. +1 also to removing recompile and indexes.

Comment: Do you use autocommit in your SqlClient or do you commit explicitly?  It may be a locking/deadlock problem.

Comment: Are you inserting ocr updating the MessageLog table in the same transaction as the SP-call, when using the c# application?

Comment: Or, are you modifying the same table from another connection? "Forever" means that your query needs to acquire a lock over the entire table or index but found it locked for some other reason (eg because other code is writing to the table). Use SQL Profiler to see what is going on or at least check Activity Monitor to see what queries are running when the wait occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option I can schedule these stored procedures to be run by
>
> SQL Server itself on an interval or specific time?

Yes, **SQL Server Agent** can run jobs based on specific time or interval.

[Creating SQL Server Job](http://sqlserverscribbles.com/2013/06/08/how-to-create-sql-server-agent-jobs/)

SSMS -> SQL Server Agent -> Right-Click -> New Job -> Select Name, Database, Code and Schedule

When you finish you can click `Script` button and get script that create job (if needed).

You can also start Job using T-SQL (for example from application/another stored procedure or trigger):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JobName';
```

Comment: @Leon For hunting for deadlock I suggest `sp_whoisactive`