# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized Error during inserting data to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm currently using .NET Web Api to register a user into SQL Server using a stored procedure. When I'm trying to add record to the database, I get an error

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

I have looked up on the internet to change the connection string but the result is still the same. When I'm debugging, code execution goes to this line

```
db.ExecNonQuery("SSO_Register", parm)
```

in the `doRegister` method and then throws the exception. Please help.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="_cs" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-KR81RU5\MSSConQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=HISDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=3600" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

`dbUtil` class:

```
private static string _cs = null;

public dbUtil(string cs)
{
    _cs = cs;
}

public void ExecNonQuery(string sp, SqlParameter[] parm)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_cs))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sp, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandTimeout = 120;

            connection.Open();

            if (parm != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < parm.Length; i++)
                    command.Parameters.Add(parm[i]);
            }

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

`doRegister` method:

```
bool _return = false;

try
{
    string tac = " ";

    Test util = new Test();
    tac = Test.getTac();

    SqlParameter[] parm =
                {
                    new SqlParameter("secure_word", objsso.secure_word),
                    new SqlParameter("full_name", objsso.full_name),
                    new SqlParameter("phone_number", objsso.phone_number),
                    new SqlParameter("nationality", objsso.nationality),
                    new SqlParameter("id_number", objsso.id_number),
                    new SqlParameter("dob", objsso.dob),
                    new SqlParameter("email", objsso.email),
                    new SqlParameter("user_id", objsso.email),
                    new SqlParameter("full_name", objsso.full_name),
                    new SqlParameter("provider_id", objsso.provider_id),
                    new SqlParameter("temp_token", objsso.temp_token),
                    new SqlParameter("tac", tac)
                 
            };

    dbUtil db = new dbUtil(_cs);
    db.ExecNonQuery("SSO_Register", parm);
    _return = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _return = false;
    throw ex;
}

return _return;
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395222/c-sharp-database-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized?rq=1

Comment: `_return = false;` is a no-op because it is followed by `throw;`. You may as well just make the function `void`, if it returns without exception then it succeeded

Comment: Debug your own code. What is the actual value of _cs when you pass it to create the connection? Or simply test it and throw an error - these are basic debugging techniques you should already know. We cannot know your application logic and why the content of that string is not set properly. More imporantly, something seems strange in doRegister - how does that method/function have access to private member _cs of dbUtil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading the connection string from Configuration so in you case connection sting is null.

```
var connectionString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["_cs"].ConnectionString;

dbUtil db = new dbUtil(connectionString );
```

Please try this one.

Comment: Hi this is the most sensible answer. But when i try, the query takes too long(almost never ending) try execute my Store Procedure on Sql studio and it returns with a 0 value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684603/cmd-executenonquery-very-slow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311130/very-slow-executenonquery-stored-procedure-vs-fast-execution-using-sql-server